# MATLAB tic-toc results in Minutes format

Tags: matlab, timer

I am using tic-toc function in my Matlab project as many places.  The output time can be `331.5264 or 1234.754 seconds`, etc.  Can I output this is minutes format?  For eg. `5 minutes and 30.6 seconds`? Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All you have to do is capture the output from [`toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) (instead of letting it display its default output), then create an output yourself using the functions [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), [`floor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html), and [`rem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rem.html):

```
 tStart = tic;
 % Do some things...
 tEnd = toc(tStart);
 fprintf('%d minutes and %f seconds\n', floor(tEnd/60), rem(tEnd,60));
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know you could control which tic a toc was referencing.

Answer (score 5):

While tic and toc do not have any way to display values in minutes, you can process the data slightly before displaying it.  Check out the following [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22817-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds) to a seconds to hour/minute converter.

Usage would be as follows:

```
tic  
% Do something
time_str = SECS2HMS(toc)
disp(time_str)
```

I will try this out when I get back on my Windows VM.  Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
You could use the datestr and datenum function built into Matlab as well in the following way.  Note that I have not tried this code either, but the link reminded me of the syntax on how to do it (without bringing up Matlab)

```
tic
%Do something  
t=toc;
disp(datestr(datenum(0,0,0,0,0,t),'HH:MM:SS'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I've found is to use:

`TIME = tic;
% do calculations which take TIME to complete
fprintf('This took %s', duration([0, 0, toc(TIME)]));`

(`toc()` [returns the time from the stopwatch in seconds](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html), and `duration()` [expects a three-column matrix expressing a time duration in [hours, minutes, seconds] format](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html)).

This has the nice property of keeping most of the timing calculations out of sight.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This one suited me:

```
    disp(['Elapsed time is ' num2str(round(toc/60,1)) ' minutes.'])
```